# How to find out which service uses a certain CPU core?

Tags: cpu

How can I find out which process/application uses Core number 4?

As I saw in Htop there isn't any application which uses high CPU, but still my fan is running "wild" and also the CPU graphic in Htop is 100%.

[image: HTOP]

Comment: I don't know how to determine which process runs on a specific core, but I had a similar case once where 'System Monitor' didn't show all processes. Usually '(sudo) top' should list everything including the process which maxed out your 4th core.

Comment: I've found out. I have opened System Monitor --> Processes --> View All Processes. After that I've seen that the "apport" process was eating around 80%.